# How to do single ajax call on controller action with all fields data for model validation in cakephp?

Tags: jquery, ajax, cakephp

Here is my ajax code for submit action:

```
$('form').submit(function(e){   

        $('.default').each(function(){
            var self = this;

                $.post( 
                    '/cakephp/Packages/validate_form',
                    {field:$(this).attr('id'),value:$(this).val()
                    },
                    function(error){

                        handleNameValidation(error,self)                    
                    }
                );
                function handleNameValidation(error,el){
                     var $parent = $(el).parent();
                        if(error.length>0){

                                if($('span.error-message',$parent).length==0){
                                $parent.append('<span class="error-message">'+ error + '</span>');
                                }
                        }
                        else{
                             $parent.removeClass('error-message');
                             $('span.error-message',$parent).fadeOut();
                        }
                }       
        });
        // Prevent form submission
          e.preventDefault();

    });
```

Here i did ajax submit and it works with model validation but here I pass the single  field id and value so that it will do many ajax call to validate . But I want to pass all available field data at single ajax call and want to do model validation.Here is my controller action

```
public function validate_form(){        
        if($this->request->is('ajax')){
            $this->request->data['Package'][$this->request['data']['field']]=$this->request['data']['value'];
            $this->Package->set($this->request->data);
            if($this->Package->validates()){
                $this->autoRender=false;

            }
            else{

                $error=$this->validateErrors($this->Package);

                $this->set('error',$this->Package->validationErrors[$this->request['data']['field']][0]);
                $this->render('validate_form','ajax');
                }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Show us your HTML form. Do you generate the form using CakePHP FormHelper ?

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to post an example, but because you do not provide the way your form is generated it could not fit exactly with wath you want.

I assume you're generating the form with the CakePHP `FormHelper` with default `name` attributes so your name attributes look like `data[Package][fieldname]`.

This is the way I use, there is other way to do this.

First, the ajax code:

```
$('form').on('submit', function (e) {

    e.preventDefault() ;

    $.post('/cakephp/Packages/validate_form', $(this).serialize(), function (data) {
        if ('error' in data) {
            for (var fieldname in data['value']) {
                var input = $('*[name="data[Package][' + fieldname + ']"') ;
                if (fieldname in data['error']) {
                    var errorInfo = data['error'][fieldname] ;
                    // This field is not ok, do what you want
                }
                else {
                    // This field is ok, do what you want
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            var updateValue = data['value'] ;
            // Everything is fine, do what you want
        }
    }) ;

}) ;
```

Then the PHP code (I'm not using any view):

```
if($this->request->is('ajax')) {
    $this->autoRender = false ;
    $this->response->type('text/x-json'); // Or something else
    $package = $this->data ;
    if($this->Package->save($package)){
        $package = $this->Package->read() ; // If your save method update data
    }
    else {
        $error = $this->validateErrors($this->Package);
    }
    if (isset($error)) {
        echo json_encode(array('error' => $error, 'value' => $package[$this->Package->name])) ;
    }
    else {
        echo json_encode(array('value' => $package[$this->Package->name])) ;
    }
}
```

This is one way to do what you want, there are better ways, I did not check the above code but it should show you the main idea behind a ajax post with cakephp.